# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Socket.io e Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket, ssl, socket.io

Estou rodando um servidor Node.js utilizando  o Socket.io para gerenciar as conexões via Socket, porém, estou tendo um problema com certificados SSL. A maioria dos usuários consegue acessar o servidor Node.js normalmente, mas outros não conseguem e recebem o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro exibido aos usuários]

Quando configuro meu servidor, estou com as seguintes opções de SSL:

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/root/cert/key.key', 'utf8').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/root/cert/cert.crt', 'utf8').toString();
var ca = fs.readFileSync('/root/cert/ca.crt').toString();
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca };
var app = express();
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer);
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse erro? O que problema é o fato de que apenas alguns usuários tem esse erro.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Adiciona o código do seu client por gentileza.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta colocar explicitamente a segurança SSL no lado cliente:

`var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:PORTA', {secure: true});`

Confere se está usando httpS no lado cliente

Answer (score -2):

Verique se o servidor há certificado SSL. Estava acontecendo o mesmo erro comigo mas ao mudar de  `const socket = io('https://localhost:4000');` para somente `http://` não ocorreu mais o erro pois o servidor não possui certificado SSL.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).